# Use password with doublequotes for cmdkey

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to execute the following command to automatically connect to remote desktop with specified credentials:

cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/{ip} /user:{user} /pass:{password} && mstsc /v:{ip}

The problem is that cmdkey doesn't recognise " as a simple character. So if password contains " there is no way to save it through cmdkey. At least I haven't found a way to escape it. I tried \", ^", '"', """ and other weird combinations, but neither of them work. Is there a way to escape it? Or is there other command that can do the same thing?

Comment: I'd try `/pass:"pass""word"` for `pass"word` (enclose `{password}` in a pair of double quotes _and_ **double** every inner double quote.

Comment: In Windows `cmd`, `^` is the escape character, so precede every `"` (also also other special characters) by such; so the literal string `pass"word` needs to be written as `pass^"word`...

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ, unfortunately it doesn't work. Everything after "pass" is just ignored and "pass""word" is interpreted as _pass_.

Comment: Thank for suggestion @aschipfl, seems that's not true for cmdkey as for /pass:pass^"word it prompts me to enter password manually (as if I left it blank).

Comment: `/pass:pass^"^"^"word`

Comment: @JosefZ, same thing as with /pass:pass^"word :( 
I tried to set password as _pass^^word_ and _pass^word_ to check if ^ is treated as a special character. But both /pass:"pass^word" and /pass:"pass^^word" worked just fine. So I believe that ^ doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: Update: But ^ do something outside double quotes. For password _pass^^word_ I have to enter `pass:/pass^^^^word` I can't understand why it doesn't work for double-quotes.

Comment: The `^` character only relates to `cmd`; perhaps `cmdkey` requires another escaping of `"`: you could try with `\^"` (`^"` becomes a literal `"` when parsed by `cmd`; maybe `cmdkey` needs such `"` to be escaped like `\"` then)...

Comment: @aschipfl, `\^"` doesn't work as well. It's interesting how `^` escapes literally every character except for `"`. I also haven't found any way to escape characters inside "double-quotes", both \ and `^` are interpreted as they are.

Comment: This is because `cmd` recognises `"` and does no longer detect special characters like `^` after one `"`; after the 2nd `"`, special characters are detected again; so detection of special characters is toggled off and on at each `"`. The `\ `is nothing special to `cmd`, it was just a guess that `cmdkey` could use this as espace character, but that's not the case unfortunately, sorry...

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate your help @aschipfl.

Answer (score 0):

How about running it in Powershell?

$p = "{your password}"
(use backtick `to escape the double quote in the string)
and then run this from powershell:

cmdkey /add:{server} /user:{username} /pass:$p

I haven't tried with " in the string, but it works for $